# Como filtro un DataFrame por horas

Tags: python

A modo de ejemplo, voy resumir mi DataFrame como sigue:

```
data                var1  var2
2018-01-01 00:00:00  21     50
2018-01-01 01:00:00  22     51
2018-01-01 02:00:00  24     52
2018-01-01 03:00:00  26     54
2018-01-01 04:00:00  28     56
2018-01-01 05:00:00  29     54
2018-01-01 06:00:00  20     59
2018-01-01 07:00:00  24     50
2018-01-01 08:00:00  29     54
2018-01-01 09:00:00  22     53
2018-01-01 10:00:00  25     57
```

**Observación**

Bien, el DF de arriba, tiene aproximadamente 17 mil líneas, que van desde `2018-01-01 00:00:00` hasta `2019-12-31 23:00:00`

**Problema**

Necesito hacer un filtro a todas las líneas, precisamente de horarios (conservando sus características var1 y var2) que vaya desde `06:00:00` hasta `19:00:00` O sea solo necesito rescatar los valores entre esos horarios

**Tentativa de solución**

Pienso que el asunto podría resolver, siguiendo el codigo escrito abajo. Que realiza el filtro que necesito, pero solo consigo aplicarlo a un día y necesito que sea aplicado en todas las días. Debería aplicar un bucle?

```
#Filtro

mask = (df.index >= '2018-01-01 06:00:00') & (df.index <= '2018-01-01 19:00:00')
df = df[mask]
```

Me ayudan a resolverlo, por gentileza

Agradezco

Comment: Olvidé de mencionar, que realice un `index_col=0` a la columna `data` para facilitar el recorrido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma cómoda es trabajar la columna como un objeto `datetime`, para esto lo primero es convertir la cadena con [`pd.to_datetime()`](http://filtro%20=%20(df.data.dt.time%20%3E%20time(6,%200))%20&%20(df.data.dt.time%20%3C%20time(20,%200))%20%20print(df.loc%5Bfiltro,%20%5D)):

```
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df.data)
```

Luego simplemente con la parte horaria hacemos el filtro:

```
from datetime import time

filtro = (df.data.dt.time >= time(6, 0)) & (df.data.dt.time < time(20, 0))

print(df.loc[filtro, ])

                 data   var1    var2
6 2018-01-01 06:00:00     20      59
7 2018-01-01 07:00:00     24      50
8 2018-01-01 08:00:00     29      54
9 2018-01-01 09:00:00     22      53
```

Ahora, si tu columna va a ser `index` al convertirla se transformará en un [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) e incluso resulta más simple todo:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

filtro = (df.index.hour >= 6) & (df.index.hour < 20)
print(df.loc[filtro, ])
```

Comment: Genial, funcionó perfecto. Había encontrado una solución similar en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312818/how-to-filtering-datetime-column-for-hours-interval-just-hours-in-pandas

Pero el código de usted, es más simple y fácil de entender. Muchas gracias